# How I Let A User Select A Folder To Save Excel File with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I obtained data from MySQL database with PHP script, and after I want export the data to MS Excel file, I managed to export but the aplication itselfs that supported Download with the script bellow, I used the PHPExcel lib:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$name = 'a_name';
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition:inline;filename='.$name.'.xls');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Before exporting the data,I want that the application displays the user a dialog box that asks where to save, How i can do it ?

thank you in advance

Comment: It's a browser option, and cannot be done on the server side.

Comment: Because i see before this option but with a J2EE application

Comment: Mozilla support that feature.. But you can't do it in server side. PHP doesn't have that method.